# ¿Cómo puedo guardar las valoraciones en arreglos que da el usuario?

Tags: array, c, contador

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int libros();
int leerunlibro(int selec);
int disponibilidad();
int valorar();
int inicio();
int main()
{
    libros();
    int selec;
    int ap;
    inicio();
}
int inicio()
{
    int opc;
    printf("Bienvenido a la biblioteca, por favor seleccione la opción que guste:\n1)
    Tomar prestado un libro\n2) Valorar la biblioteca virtual UAG\n");
    scanf("%d",&opc);
    switch (opc)
    {
        case 1:
        leerunlibro(opc);
        break;
        
        case 2:
        valorar();
        break;
    }
}
int libros()
{
    int nr;
    printf("Aviso antes de iniciar el programa, cuando le hagan alguna pregunta la respuesta si es 1 y no es 2\n");
    printf("Ingrese su número de registro"); printf (" R: ");
    scanf("%d",&nr);
}
int leerunlibro(int opc)
{
    int ap;
    int decision;
    int dec;
    printf("Seleccione el libro que quiera apartar\n");
    disponibilidad();
    printf("Desea apartarlo? 1= Si 2= No\n");
    scanf("%d",&decision);
    switch (decision)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            printf("Ha apartado su libro, desea apartar otro y volver al menú?\n");
            scanf("%d",&dec);
            if (dec==1)
            {
                leerunlibro(opc);
            }
            if (dec==2)
            {
                printf("Gracias por visitar la biblioteca virtual");
                exit (-1);
                break;
            }
        }    
        
        case 2:
        printf("Desea volver al menú?\n");
        scanf("%d",&dec);
        if (dec==1)
            {
                leerunlibro(opc);
            }
        if (dec==2)
        {
            printf("Gracias por visitarte la biblioteca virtual");
            exit (-1);
            break;
        }
        
    }
}
int disponibilidad()
{
    int opc;
    int mnu;
    printf("1) Rapid Development. Steve McConnell, 1996.\n2) Design Patterns. Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson y John M. Vlissides. 1994\n3) Software Configuration Management Pattern. Stephen Berczuk y Brad Appleton, 2003.\n4) Object-Oriented: Software Construction. Bertrand Meyer, 1988.\n5) Lean Software Development: An Agile Toolkit. Mary y Tom Poppendieck, 2003.\n");
    scanf("%d",&opc);
    switch (opc)
    {
        case 1:
        printf("El libro está disponible en estas bibliotecas/sucursales:\n1) Bilioteca UAG\n2) Librerías Gonvill Andares\n");
        break;
        
        case 2:
        printf("Disculpe, el libro no está disponible en ninguna sucursal.\n");
        printf("Desea volver al menú principal?\n");
        scanf("%d",&mnu);
        if (mnu==1)
        {
            inicio();
        }
        if (mnu==2)
        printf("Gracias por visitarte por la biblioteca virtual");
        exit (-1);
        break;
        
        case 3:
        printf ("El libro está disponible en estas bibliotecas/sucursales:\n1) Biblioteca Efraín González Morfín\n2) Librerías Gonvill Centro\n");
        break;
        
        case 4: 
        printf("Disculpe, el libro no está disponible en ninguna sucursal.\n");
        printf("Desea volver al menú principal?\n");
        scanf("%d",&mnu);
        if (mnu==1)
        {
            inicio();
        }
        if (mnu==2)
        printf("Gracias por visitar la biblioteca virtual");
        exit (-1);
        break;
        
        break;
        case 5:printf ("El libro está disponible en estas bibliotecas/sucursales:\n1) Librerías Gandhi Av. Patria\n");
    }
}
int valorar()
{
    int calif;
    char *valoraciones[] = {"1) Mala", "2) No tan mal", "3) Regular", "4) Buena", "5) Increíble 10/10" };
    int v, tam = sizeof(valoraciones) / sizeof(char *);
    for (v = 0; v<tam; ++v)
       printf("%s\n",valoraciones[v]);
       printf("\n");
       printf("Por favor, a continuación califique su experiencia con la biblioteca virtual UAG\n");
       scanf("%d",&calif);
       printf("Gracias por su valoración, vuelva pronto");
    return 0;
```

En la función `valorar` busco que con otro arreglo o con el mismo pueda guardar la calificacion que ha dado el usuario, por ejemplo, si calificó una vez con un 2 de 5, se muestre que calificó con un dos una vez, si vuelve a calificar con un dos que salga que ha calificado con un dos, dos veces, debe ser con un arreglo, muchas gracias!

[image: Es lo que se puede hacer para poder guardar las valoraciones, pero no he logrado hacerlo]

Las calificaciones deben ser necesariamente con números

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las calificaciones son un dato numérico entero que se encuentra en el rango [1, 5], es decir, puede tener 5 valores diferentes. Lo que necesita el programa es llevar la cuenta de las diferentes valoraciones.

La forma de representar esto sería un array de tipo entero con 5 posiciones:

```
int main()
{
    int calificaciones[5] = {};
}
```

Lo único que debe hacer ahora tu función es coger este array e incrementar en uno la puntuación que marque el usuario:

```
int valorar(int calificaciones[])
{
    int calif;
    char *valoraciones[] = {"1) Mala", "2) No tan mal", "3) Regular", "4) Buena", "5) Increíble 10/10" };
    int tam = sizeof(valoraciones) / sizeof(char *);
    for (int v = 0; v<tam; ++v) 
    {
       puts(valoraciones[v]);
    }

    puts("");
    puts("Por favor, a continuación califique su experiencia con la biblioteca virtual UAG");

    int calif;
    scanf("%d",&calif);
  
    calificaciones[calif-1]++;

    puts("Gracias por su valoración, vuelva pronto");
    return 0;
}
```

Aunque para evitar sustos, sería recomendable validar la entrada del usuario:

```
while(1)
{
    int calif;
    scanf("%d",&calif);
    if (calif >= 1 && calif <= 5) break;

    puts("Por favor introduzca un valor del 1 al 5");
}

calificaciones[calif-1]++;
```